# Using Apache RedirectPermanent to send all requests to a specific subfolder

Tags: apache-2.4, 301-redirect, redirection

Having asked a long and convoluted question earlier, I now have some code here using `RedirectPermanent` that I need help with.

We're merging an old site into the new one, and don't care about mapping all the ancient urls to anywhere on the new site, so all of it should be permanently redirected to a special index.php that will decide if/where to redirect with php.

The exception is one subdomain, it should do the same thing, but to a different index.php.

This is the "pseudo-config" I'm trying to accomplish - slight variations will work, but I can't get it to ignore the full path of the request, and unconditionally go to my choice of index.php with the querystring.

```
#Subdomain from old site:
#Process querystring from root\oldsite\subdomain\index.php
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.oldsite.com
    RedirectPermanent / http://www.newsite.com/oldsite/subdomain/index.php  
</VirtualHost>

#ALL other requests of any kind regardless of path
#Process querystring from root\oldsite\index.php
# Must show www.newsite.com, NOT www.oldsite.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName oldsite.com
    ServerAlias www.oldsite.com
    RedirectPermanent / http://www.newsite.com/oldsite/index.php    
</VirtualHost>
```

The DNS has been set so that everything from the old site goes to this server, and these are the first VirtualHost entries in the config file.  How do i modify this code to go to the given index.php *regardless* of the path.

```
www.oldsite.com                       ==> www.newsite.com\oldsite\index.php
www.oldsite.com/forum/anything/else   ==> www.newsite.com\oldsite\index.php
www.oldsite.com/faq/category/chosen   ==> www.newsite.com\oldsite\index.php
www.oldsite.com/about/us/index.php    ==> www.newsite.com\oldsite\index.php
subdomain.oldsite.com/anthing         ==> www.newsite.com\oldsite\subdomain\index.php
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redirect is not the correct one to use for what you seek. Redirect redirects "all" and "appends that all" to the destination, but you want a final single destination, so.. use this instead:

```
RedirectMatch ^ http://newsite.example.com/oldsite/subdomain/index.php
```

This will redirect everything to the destination you specify, without appending anything else.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Is there a way to capture what the original url and querystring was for processing in that index.php

Comment: this other question is not a simple redirect, just pass the request to the next domain for it to handle. I would indeed use a `Redirect / http://newsite.example.com/` to make sure the original request gets passed along  and in the destination I would just have a `FallbackResource /path/to/index.php` or something of that fashion, to make sure the main controller gets what has been requested.

Comment: And to use HTTP 301 instead of 302, you can add 301 after RedirectMatch: https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/301-redirect-with-mod_rewrite-or-redirectmatch/#301_Redirects_RedirectMatch